# Saving Saving Enity + Nested List to Web API via AJAX

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm currently working on a web forms (not MVC) application using WebAPI 2 controllers for ajax calls.

I'm attempting to create/update an object that also contains a list of another entity inside:

Here's a trimmed down version of the entity object:.

```
public partial class POHdr
{
    public int POHdrID { get; set; }

...snip...

    public POHdr()
    {
        this.POLine = new List<POLine>();
    }

    public virtual List<POLine> POLine { get; set; }
}
```

The ajax call is this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: ajaxURL,
    type: "PUT",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: jOBJ,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (msg) {
        AJAXSuccess(msg);
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        AJAXError(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
});
```

The 'jOBJ' (which is a result of JSON.stringify) looks like this:

```
"{"ExchRate":"","DelAddr1":"","DelAddr2":"","DelAddr3":"","DelAddr4":"","DelAddr5":"","OrderDate":"","ReqdDate":"","Phone":"234234","Mobile":"342","Email":"Test","Fax":"","Contact":"","POLine":"[{\"Estimate\":\"123\",\"StockDesc\":\"namedesc\",\"LineSort\":0}]"}"
```

The controller is just a normal webapi2 with entity actions controller, and is receiving/saving the POHdr object no problem, but the POLine is always empty when it comes into the controller.

I've had a look and have only found solutions that relate to MVC, or require 2 seperate calls to save, ideally I would like to save this as one. Is this possible?

EDIT: As requested, here is the code for POLine, I would like to add that the [DataContract]/[DataMember] is in the POHdr too, I removed it for readability's sake.

```
[DataContract]
public partial class POLine
{
    [DataMember]
    public int POLineID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<int> CompanyID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<int> POHdrID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<int> LineSort { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<int> StockID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Stockcode { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string StockDesc { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<int> StkUOMID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<double> OrderQty { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<double> UnitPrice { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<bool> Estimate { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<double> Discount { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<double> LineValue { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<double> GST { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreateDate { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastUpdated { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ReqdDate { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual Stock Stock { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual POHdr POHdr { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT 2 : Relevant Code for the controller

```
[ResponseType(typeof(void))]
public IHttpActionResult PutItem(int id, POHdr item)
{
    try
    {
        Actions.UpdateItem(id, item);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }
    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}

// POST: api/PurchaseOrder
[ResponseType(typeof(POHdr))]
public IHttpActionResult PutItem(POHdr item)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    Actions.AddItem(item);
    return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = item.POHdrID }, item);
}
```

Comment: You're doing what you exactly have to do. You can do it with a single call. It's really strange that you're getting an empty list. Please, show the POLine class, and the Web API action code. By the way it doesn't matter if it's MVC or Web Forms. You're dealing with Web API, which is independent of both.

Comment: Please, remove the virtual modifier and check again. it's the only unusual thing I see in your code.

Comment: @JotaBe I have added the code for POLine, I would add that the code is all generated by EF as i'm running DB first (client DB, hence the horribad table names), I did change the template to use List instead of ICollection to fix some other issues.

I removed virtual and tested, same issue.

Comment: Do you have the POHdr object and the POLine property decorated with [DataContract] and [DataMember] ?

Comment: Have answered the question below, cause was bad JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the JSON string was not valid (I hadn't run it through a validator to check)

The way the array was encoded was resulting in the array for 'POLine' just being a garbage string rather than actual json (which is why there are backslashes in the string).

Comment: Hod did you get a bad JSON with JSON.stringify? You told it was generated using it, so I supposed it was valid... ???

Comment: This part of the JSON is bad - ""POLine":"[{\"Estimate\":\"123\",\"StockDesc\":\"namedesc\",\"LineSort\":0}]""

Basically, I had earlier just strinigfy'd the POLine object when I was working on the code to build this line, and as a result was attaching the string rather than the object to the POHdr JSON Object, which was turning the POLine property into a string rather than the array it should have been.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation. I couldn't understand how an invalid JSON was being genrated by JSON.stringify. It was too strange!